# How to plot this in iwork-numbers

Tags: charts, iwork-numbers

I have an array of data like this

0,1
0,56
0,4
0,57
0,6
0,006
0,34
0,46
...

I have another array of data that classifies the data above in categories like this:

from 0,1 to 0,5   category A
from 0,51 to 0,56 category B 
…

I need to plot the data in function to the categories. How can I do that in iwork-numbers 09'?

Comment: After initial joy that iWork was "kinda working" I let it lie. The metaphors are so different from Excel that was getting tired learning it and kept using Excel when I want to deliver something that others who use Excel can work on. When I want to plot something that should look acceptable, I usually use ploticus after massaging the data with Excel or perl.